# How to add cell data in tableviewcell to type exercise name, add category, and select type in uitableviewcontroller through code swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm building a fitness application that is going to allow you to add a PR and you need to be able to fill out the Name of the exercise, The Type of exercise, The Category, and the lbs in weight. Then when you fill all of those out you can click done and have it displayed in another tableviewcontroller.

[image: My Table View Controller]

I want to do this with uitableviewcells through swift code. I'm fairly new to using tableviews and cells and was wondering if I could get some insight on how I would do this?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you need help with. Is the screenshot what you have so far? If so, I would just put a "save" button somewhere on it, and then save the exercise data somewhere (either locally or to a database on a server depending on your use case). Then create another tableview that displays all your exercise data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm trying to let the user fill out data in the view controller I have linked above. I want to be able to programmatically add a done button and link it to an IBAction which I already have. When that is clicked I want the data to be stored locally in the app and display it on the home view controller. I'm having trouble allowing a user to edit the cell's as well.

Comment: @toddg Here is my reply